# Browse "Close Votes" by tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, review, vote-to-close

I tried to browse posts in **Close Votes** section from **Review Beta** by tag. I think it is not possible or at least I couldn't figure it out.

I think it will be interesting to enable this option as it is easier and faster to judge close votes about a topic you are kind of expert at. When I review close votes I select "not sure" button for most of them.

I believe that **browsing close votes by tag** will encourage users to review more close votes.

Comment: It's not totally obvious, but the questions you see are already picked according to your "favorite" tags preference and the tags you're active in.

Comment: @Shog9 I didn't know that. Anyway it is still kind of random isn't it? For example it is not possible to combine to tags like **[tag1][tag2]**. I think that would make a lot more interesting the reviewing.

Comment: I spend **a lot** of time clicking "Not sure" on Stackoverflow, because I am completely unable to evaluate if the question or answer is OK or not. I have a few tags set as favorites, but it doesn't seem to help much.